# How to open a .txt file in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a website using the Flask framework for Python.

I'm on a Linux Ubuntu server, with Apache2.

On my website, whenever someone enters the URL `"/Elv_1.html"`, I want to open a `.txt` file, get some values and create a graph using `pygal`. Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/river_1.html')
def riv_1():
    try:
        document = open('temp.txt','r')

        temp_list = []
        for n in document:
            n = n.rstrip('\n')
            n = int(n)
            temp_list.append(n)

        document.close()

        graf = pygal.Line(title=u'Tempt last 24h')
        graf.x_labels = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
        graf.add('Temp', temp_list)
        graf = graf.render_data_uri()

        return render_template('river_1.html', graf=graf)
    except Exception, e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The file `'temp.txt'` is located in the same directory as the `__init__.py` file. `__init__.py` is the Flask app that the code comes from.

When I do this on my computer using localhost to run the server, it works just fine. However, when I upload this to my Linux server and try to enter that specific URL, it shows the following error:

> [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'temp.txt'

Any suggestions as to why it doesn't appear to find the file?

Comment: Does the file exist on the server too? That is, did you upload the `temp.txt` too to the server, not only the Python program?

Comment: seems like the file is not in the same directory as flask file. see if that is the issue. these problems are usually found due to incorrect name or incorrect path

Comment: when you run your application on local, they are aside, but on server, you may call your app using `wsgi server`, (will, you should if you aren't!), there is a bit difference between python path there, and you shold change the way you give `path` to files.

Comment: Yes, the file is uploaded to the server.

Comment: my __init__.py is in the same folder as temp.txt

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `os` module when specifying the path to your file. I am asuming you are using a windows pc when runing  on localhost?

```
import os
document_path = os.getcwd()+'temp.txt'
document = open(documnet_path, 'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the server from it's directory. So if you have this structure as shown below, you can't simply open terminal and type `server/__init__.py`, because you are in your home directory (`/home/username/`). You need to `cd` to `server` and there run `./__init__.py`

```
/home/
  username/
    server/
      __init__.py
      temp.txt
```

Or, if you want to run it from somewhere else, run open the file from `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/temp.txt')` (Tested with python 3.5.2)
See python docs for `os.path`.